# How to protect a file with a password then unprotect it later (in a user proof way)

Tags: windows, encryption, installer

I'd like to protect a file with a strong symmetric encryption (preferably AES).
So that I can distribute the file freely.

Once the file is on place I need a user proof way to unprotect the file and copy it to specified directory. 
Unprotecting should be a single click operation with password prompt and an notification when everything went ok. Ie. the unprotecting operation should decrypt the file and copy it to an hard coded path.

Do you know any programs that could do that for me?

I was thinking about an exe generator from protected zip file?but i'm not sure if that is the best approach. (the encryption isn't best but it is acceptable)

Comment: I don't see what *unprotect it at given time* has to do with your question? And are you expecting the user to enter some password, or does the single click imply that no password is needed?

Comment: Arjan thank you for point the unclear bits out. I've improved the question. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess a self-extractor is indeed the easiest solution for you and your users, but would imply that all users have the same password. Many ZIP utilities support it, including [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (with AES-256).

[Paquet Builder](http://www.gdgsoft.com/pb/) shows [a nice GUI](http://www.gdgsoft.com/faq/7zsfx.htm), but is not free.

Comment: I use 7zip and it's excellent (I use it as a Total Commander plugin).

Comment: 7-zip seems to be the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: (I find it quite odd how quickly answers are accepted. 1/4th of the world, like most users from the northern americas, were even asleep during this half hour... I'm sure there's quite some differences in the GUIs supplied by the various ZIP utilities, and I am not confident 7-Zip offers the best. Of course, one could also easily find those using Google.)

Comment: You are right but I will probably go with 7zip anyway and I always accept the answer that I'm using. Is that bad?